# How do I set the logging level in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I would like to change the logging level of my Quarkus application.

How can I do that either from the configuration file or at runtime?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The property that controls the root logging level is `quarkus.log.level` (and defaults to `INFO`).

This property can be set either in `application.properties` or can be overridden at runtime using `-Dquarkus.log.level=DEBUG`.

You can also specify more fine grained logging using `quarkus.log.category`.

For example for RESTEasy you could set:

```
quarkus.log.category."org.jboss.resteasy".level=DEBUG
```

For more information about logging in Quarkus, please check [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging-guide) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Just a detail, if you want to set the log level using VM Options.

From the docs:

> If you add these properties on the command line, ensure the "
> character is escaped properly:
>
> -Dquarkus.log.category.\"org.hibernate\".level=TRACE

Documentation:
https://quarkus.io/guides/logging