# How to configure Quarkus log level?

Tags: quarkus

I want to change the log level of my quarkus app, and everywhere where I could find any reference, it pointed me to the application.properties file.

This is my application.properties content:

```
quarkus.log.level=TRACE
quarkus.log.console.enable=true
quarkus.log.console.level=TRACE

"%test".quarkus.log.level=TRACE
"%test".quarkus.log.console.enable=true
"%test".quarkus.log.console.level=TRACE
```

And this is my code:

```
Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessorController.class);

 LOGGER.trace("TRACE");
 LOGGER.debug("DEBUG");
 LOGGER.info("INFO");
 LOGGER.error("ERROR");
```

But this is the output:

```
Feb 24, 2020 1:42:35 PM com.MyClass greetings
INFO: INFO
Feb 24, 2020 1:42:35 PM com.MyClass greetings
ERROR: ERROR
```

Do I need any extra extension to get it working?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044060/how-do-i-set-the-logging-level-in-quarkus) but it didn't work for me.
I really have no idea, I created a simple app from the Quarkus bootstrap and I still have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what was going on.
It seems that the yaml-config dependency does not recognize as a valid entry

```
quarkus.log.level:  WARN
```

but

```
quarkus:
  log:
    level:  WARN
```

works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can't use SLF4J's log levels on the properties file as far as I know. You need to use any of the values from `java.utils.logging.Level`.

And as the Javadoc says, those are:

```
SEVERE (highest value)
WARNING
INFO
CONFIG
FINE
FINER
FINEST (lowest value)
```

I've replaced my config to `quarkus.log.category."com.my.package".level=FINEST` and `log.trace("MSG");` from SLF4J worked as intended.

Comment: This is an excerpt from the answer in the question I linked and comes from a Quarkus dev: "The property that controls the root logging level is quarkus.log.level (and defaults to INFO). This property can be set either in application.properties or can be overridden at runtime using -Dquarkus.log.level=DEBUG. "
This leads me to believe this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not posible to change the logging level at runtime, as far as i could test.
As a workaround, i recommend setting the log level in the Main method before delegating to quarkus. Something like:

```
System.setProperty("quarkus.log.console.level", "DEBUG");
Quarkus.run(YourApp.class);
```

Same goes for config file locations and other system properties.